# AWS widget integration with Angular6

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, angular6

I am working on Angular 6 application where in one my feature I have files listed in grid. I want to provide facility to user to upload these files to AWS/Google Drive/Dropbox. Are there any useful blogs for same or anybody worked on similar functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Please read this blog Angular 5 File Uploads to S3 with (relative ) ease https://medium.com/@bevin.hernandez/angular-5-file-uploads-to-s3-with-relative-ease-ea19b7fd120e

```
fileEvent(fileInput: any) {
  const AWSService = AWS;
  const region = '<insert your region here>';
  const bucketName = '<insert your bucket name>';
  const IdentityPoolId = '<insert your identity pool id>';
  const file = fileInput.target.files[0];

// Configures the AWS service and initial authorization
  AWSService.config.update({
    region: region,
    credentials: new AWSService.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
      IdentityPoolId: IdentityPoolId
    })
  });

// adds the S3 service, make sure the api version and bucket are correct
  const s3 = new AWSService.S3({
    apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
    params: { Bucket: bucketName}
  });

// I store this in a variable for retrieval later
  this.image = file.name;
  s3.upload({ Key: file.name, Bucket: bucketName, Body: file, ACL: 'public-read'},
    function (err, data) { 
        if (err) { 
            console.log(err, 'there was an error uploading your file'); 
        }
 });
}
```

Comment: Hi @mruanova, In this case we are passing account details where file will be stored, But I want file to be stored on independent client AWS account who is logged in into my system. In simplistic way there will be button which will ask for AWS login on click and after selecting account, file will be uploaded to selected folder.